# Android app crashes on orientation change using ViewPager

Tags: android, google-maps

I currently am developing an app that uses a ViewPager and upon orientation changes it crashes. I have examined several different posts about this but none of them have the same error I am getting.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've added the fixes that other posts suggest, namely

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    //first saving my state, so the bundle wont be empty.
    outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY",  "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

but this didn't work.

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

is not in my code, its commented out, as suggested (I've also tried setting it to false).

I have also specified

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

which fixes the problem 90% of the time. However, if the device is closed/put to sleep and my app was the open app at the time, and then the login screen becomes landscape, the app starts up again in the background and crashes by the time the user has logged in.

EDIT: Also, the problem seems to only occur because I have two different fragements with a google maps fragment in it.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like I've tried everything.

Comment: Which version of Android? Is `google-maps` tag necessary?

Comment: I'm targeting sdk versions 16 to 18, and it is necessary because the error only occurs if I have two different maps fragments. With just one the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: To clarify, my ViewPager has three fragments, the first one has a maps fragment, the second doesn't, and the third has a different maps fragment. If I take out the second maps fragment the crash doesn't occur, I recently figured this out.

Comment: @TomW Did you fix this issue?

Comment: @surfer190 yeah, I eventually got it fixed. I was nesting fragments using xml instead of the child support fragment manager (I think that's what fixed it, it's been a while). I had to read up on how to nest fragments for a bit before I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Once I had the same problem. You added GoogleMap fragment in XML. However, [documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments) says:

> **Note:** You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes
>   a `<fragment>`. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a
>   fragment dynamically.

In your case, you want to inflate a layout with GoogleMaps `<fragment>` into ViewPager fragment, you can't do that.

You should add GoogleMap fragment to the ViewPager from the Java code, for example with ViewGroup's (or its subclass)[`addView(View v)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method.